# Spring MVC: Centralised Processing of Form Validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, model-view-controller

I have an application that has many data entry screens, hence there are many controller classes that are accepting various forms as POST data. The forms use javax validation annotations and the controllers are using the BindingResult to check for errors. Some of the forms use a custom validator (implementing Springs ValidationUtils) to do more validation.

I am now trying to centralise form validation (to remove repeating validation code in each controller) into a separate class using the @ControllerAdvice approach and removing the BindingResult from the controller method's parameters. Removing the Binding result throws an error which is caught by the ControllerAdvice class.

This all works nicely EXCEPT for the fact that only the basic annotations like @Max, @Min are present in the BindingResult in the ControllerAdvice class and not the more complex validations from the custom validator.

Is there a way to get the custom validation errors into the ControllerAdvice class? What other approaches have you taken to centralising form validation handling?

Thanks!

Code Below:

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String save(@Valid @RequestBody EmployeeForm form, 
HttpServletRequest request) 
{

}
```

**EmployeeFormValidator.java**

```
@Component
public class EmployeeFormValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return EmployeeFormValidator.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) 
    {
        EmployeeFormValidator form = (EmployeeFormValidator) obj;

        e.reject("firstName", "Please populate the employee's first name field.");


    }

}
```

**ExceptionControllerAdvice.java**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {


    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public @ResponseBody String handleException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if(ex.getBindingResult() != null) {
            BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();

            return "Binding errors found.";

        }else {

            return "No binding errors found.";
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you are using Spring, all you have to do is annotate @Valid. Rest would be encap;sulated in validators.

Comment: Please, post the code to reproduce

Comment: @Hitham S. AlQadheeb - just attached it now to the post, thanks